# Connector between spark and neo4j container

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, containers, cluster-computing

I'm new to spark and neo4j and needed help setting them up.

My goal is to read an HDFS file in spark and put/represent it in neo4j. Can someone help me create a connector between spark and neo4j, but neo4j being a container? I'm a little lost among everything I find on the internet, and I'm not getting results in my container.

I'm trying to follow this link https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector. But for example, I can't find my pom.xml file to change it. Do I have to create a new one and put it on neo4j?

And for this connection, the spark must be inside the neo4j container? Or can it be in the cluster, outside the container, and do they recognize each other?

Any help is good! Thank you!

Comment: This is really a question about networking rather than spark and neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use it as described in the README - start `spark-shell` or `spark-submit` with `--packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.4.5-M1` parameter - it will pull the necessary jars & make connector available.

Spark could be (and should be) running outside of the neo4j container, you need to pass `--conf spark.neo4j.url=Neo4j_URL` to specify the connection endpoint of Neo4j, and if necessary provide username and password via `--conf spark.neo4j.user=username` and `--conf spark.neo4j.password=password` (although you can specify them in the Neo4j URL as well...

Comment: I am following your suggestion by starting the spark-shell as you told me. But when I do

Neo4jDataFrame.mergeEdgeList(sc, df, ("Name", Seq("name")),("HAPPENED_IN", Seq.empty), ("Age", Seq("age")))
prints this error:
ERROR LoadBalancer: Failed to update routing table for database 'maria'. Current routing table: Ttl 1594170847613, currentTime 1594170848006, routers AddressSet=[], writers AddressSet=[], readers AddressSet=[], database 'maria'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the Neo4j container listens on the external ports?